# My forum queries "waiting for table lock" and slowing my whole server

Tags: mysql, performance

I experienced slow performance of my website and noticed that some queries in my `processlist` are not executing.

This is what I saw:

[image]

tens of seconds waiting for sorting result!

my forum_posts table is really big and MyISAM

[image]

How I can improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Use indexes that fit your join tables and an index that covers your `where`-conditions and `order by` (if you have different kinds of queries, use the columns that you use in all of them). If you have indexes show them to us. And your `find_in_set` looks suspicious, check if you can replace it with e.g.`=2`. And you might want to only calculate your `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` on the first query and save it. Your query doesn't look userspecific, so you might be able to cache results and reuse them.

Comment: Switch to InnoDB.  [_Tips on the conversion_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/)